# Submit HTML form to .txt file, but how to make new posts appear on top, rather than on the bottom?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, txt

Everything works perfectly however there is one thing that I am trying to figure out and I’m not sure how to actually figure this out.

On the HTML web form everything works perfectly, on the php page the takes the data that has been submitted is posted on the text file that I specify, but here is where I want to make a change.

As of right now if I make a post, the oldest post remains on top where the newest one is at the bottom which is kind of annoying having to scroll all the way to the bottom for the newest post so my question is how can I reverse this so the oldest post is at the bottom and every time I make a post the newest one is at the top?

Here is the code

```php
<?php
 $path = 'PAGE_NAME_HERE.TXT';
 if (isset($_POST['C1']) && isset($_POST['C2']) && isset($_POST['C3']) && isset($_POST['C4']) && isset($_POST['C5']) && isset($_POST['C6']) && isset($_POST['C7']) && isset($_POST['C8']) && isset($_POST['C9']) && isset($_POST['C10']) && isset($_POST['C11A']) && isset($_POST['C11'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['C1'].'  '.$_POST['C2'].'   '.$_POST['C3'].'   '.$_POST['C4'].'   '.$_POST['C5'].'  '.$_POST['C6'].'   '.$_POST['C7'].'  '.$_POST['C8'].'   '.$_POST['C9'].'   '.$_POST['C10'].'   '.$_POST['C11A'].' '.$_POST['C11'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

Comment: You could load the entire text file into a string, stick the new part onto the start of the string, and write it back out again. It's a bit clunky and will be annoying as the file gets larger. Probably why most would do this with a database table so the order of writing is irrelevant. Or, you could alter the code that reads from the file so that it starts at the end and reads backwards, though that would be quite fiddly.

Comment: Just use a database like everyone else.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I prefer not to use a database plus if I would to use a DB, I would need to start from scratch as I am not sure what I can use. If I can somehow make the new content that’s added each time a post is added than I have achieve my goal, so how can this be done?

Comment: If you don't have a free database server such as mysql available in your environment then you could use a free file-based database such as SqLite. If, for some reason, you really don't want to do that, then you can use the approach droopsnoot outlined. It isn't simple and can be fragile as well. A SQL "UPDATE" query is a lot easier to use. That's why no-one does what you're trying to do, they all use databases. If you haven't used one before, this would be a great opportunity to learn.